# supergroups rules on telegram

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I am about to open a big group on telegram for one of my projects, I would like to force on all the group members a few rules:
only english can be typing on the group.
censorship bad language.
close and open the chat from time to time.

someone maybe can help me with this?
thank you all!

Comment: Hi there, welcome to StackOverflow! This question is too broad. Do you have a _specific_ problem with implementing your group rules? Please refer to [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and take the [tour] if you haven't already. Thanks. :-)

Comment: hi,  the problem is that i dont know how to do it, how i add a new rule to my group?